# Can we use elastic search basic in our product which we sail as part of monitoring, according license?

Tags: elasticsearch

pls, help. I`m dont understand Elastic license.
We use elastic stack in our software as part of monitoring tool , can we use it with basic license ?

Comment: Elastc license: https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/7.4/licenses/ELASTIC-LICENSE.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer and not sure, but I believe that in cases where you using the `basic` license you are not allowed to compete directly with Elastic commercial offering. This is not a full answer, as I don't really know your use case and how are you going to provide your service and what will it use from the `basic` features.

I think that if you want a full answer you have to contact Elastic guys directly in discuss: https://discuss.elastic.co/